# Increment Numeric Value to just above criterion value and stop incrementing below the value in SAS using do until loop

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, do-loops

I have just started using macros and arrays in SAS and am a beginner user of SAS. I need your guidance and advice on the most effective way to increment score values which are less than 65. I have a dataset of 10 observations on their student IDs and their test scores. I have the following code to increment the test scores values which are less than 65. Is there another way I can increment test score values which are less than 65 to just above 65 so that it stops if the value is 65 or greater.

```
data scores;
set scores;
array Test{i} Test_1-Test_5;
Test{i} = 1;
do i=1 to 5;
do until(Test{i}>65);
   Test{i} = Test{i}+0.1;
end;
```

I am getting an error with this code:

```
Mixing of implicit and explicit array subscripting not allowed
There was 1 unclosed DO unblock
```

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in this code.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are two `do` loops but one `end;`. Add the second `end;` after the first one to close the `do i=1 to 5;`. And the `run;` I presume is just omitted from this snippet and not your actual code.

Comment: Why are you use a loop for a simple arithmetic calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems that have been corrected with the below code:

1. Your declared array uses the variable `i` as the dimension. `i` is not assigned a value until the outer `do` loop. Use the wildcard `*` instead. This will tell SAS to automatically generate the dimension depending on the number of variables specified in the array.
2. `Test[i]` is given a value, but `i` has not yet been assigned. Place `test[i]` within your outer `do` loop
3. You are missing an `end` statement for the outer `do` loop.

Code:

```
data test;
    array Test[*] Test_1-Test_5;

    do i=1 to 5;
        Test[i] = 1;
        do until(Test[i]>65);
            Test[i] = Test[i]+0.1;
        end;
    end;

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at your code

```
data scores;
  set scores;
  array Test{i} Test_1-Test_5;
  Test{i} = 1;
  do i=1 to 5;
    do until(Test{i}>65);
      Test{i} = Test{i}+0.1;
    end;
  ??
??
```

What is incorrect:

- The DATA step is incomplete. The ?? should be replaced with a loop terminating `end` and a step finishing `run`
- The `array` statement

  - Arrays can not be declared as dynamically sized based on a variable value, thus
    `array test{i}` is incorrect
  - An array, with no size specified, can be associated with an explicit [SAS variable list](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  The size of the array is automatically the number of variables in the list. For example:
    `array test test1-test5;`  **recommended** for this question.
  - An array, with size specified.  This automatically creates or associates variables with the array, for example
    `array test(5);`

Implicit array subscripting is an undocumented artifact from older versions of SAS that allows legacy code to continue to run.

The legacy form of array declaration involving a variable
`array Test{i} Test_1-Test_5;`
should be avoided.  This form tells SAS that when the array `test` is referenced by name only the array index to use is found in variable `i`.  Explicit reference as `test(<index>)` is not allowed.